# copyTo in AppScript activeRange.offset

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm very new to Javascript and Apps Script I'm looking to create a function that updates another sheet based on the date in a specific range of the active sheet. I run and there are no errors but it is not transferring the values from the active sheet to the named sheet "2022 YTD".

Please help me see what I'm not seeing.

```
function updateYTD3() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("January");
  if (sheet) {
    sheet.getRange("A2:D32").copyTo(ss.getSheetByName("Feb").getRange("C2"),{contentsOnly:true});
  }
}
```

[PICT1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIVB4.jpg)

[PITC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUlQL.jpg)

Comment: About `but it is not transferring the values from the active sheet to the named sheet "2022 YTD".`, in your script, the specific sheet of `January` is used as the source sheet. If the active sheet is different from `January` sheet, the reason for your current issue is due to this. If you always want to use the active sheet, please modify `const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("January");` to `const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();`.

Comment: But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `so as not to copy and paste data in the same column, copy and paste the next column (copy new data in LastColumn),`. So, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: Tanaike
 sorry im revisi code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the detail of the relationship between your updated script and your current issue?

Comment: Tanaike

im update image for detail, sorry my English is bad

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your sample images, how about modifying `sheet.getRange("A2:D32").copyTo(ss.getSheetByName("Feb").getRange("C2"),{contentsOnly:true});` to `sheet.getRange("A1:B4").copyTo(ss.getSheetByName("Feb").getRange("C1"), { contentsOnly: true });`? By this, I think that the situation of your sample image is obtained. If I misunderstood your actual expected result, I apologize.

Comment: https://youtube.com/shorts/FNLQkIMMp4o?feature=share  ,
 
Tanaike function in vba excel use in googlesheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer and discussion. I believe your goal will be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like that you are trying to copy data from the "January" sheet to the "Feb" sheet within the same spreadsheet, using the copyTo() method.

To troubleshoot this issue, you should first check if the sheet "Feb" exists within the spreadsheet. If it does not exist, the code will not be able to locate it, and the data will not be copied. To resolve this, you can add a check for the sheet's existence before calling the copyTo() method.

Additionally, you should check if the range in the target sheet is valid. If the range is not valid, the data will not be copied.
Another factor to consider is whether the range you are trying to copy from ("A2:D32") contains any data. If it does not contain any data, there will be nothing to copy.

```
function updateYTD3() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("January");
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Feb");
  if (sheet && targetSheet) {
    if(sheet.getRange("A2:D32").getValues().length > 0){
      sheet.getRange("A2:D32").copyTo(targetSheet.getRange("C2"),{contentsOnly:true});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks DanE answer, What I mean is

youtube.com/shorts/FNLQkIMMp4o?feature=share

Comment: youtube.com/shorts/FNLQkIMMp4o?feature=share